# how to hi-light something in HTML with <mark>

Tags: html, css, highlight

i am trying to make something  that highlights text black but my code isnt working

is there any way to do this?

CODE:

CSS:

```
.highlight-black {
    background-color:black;
    color:white;
}
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
    </HEAD>
    <BODY>
        <div id='highlight-black'>
            text to hilight
        </div>
    </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: use class in html, like that - `<div class='highlight-black'>`

Answer (score 1):

you using `id` in ur div and u should use `#` .

for `id` in css `#`

for `class` in css `.`

---

**class way** / using `.`

```
html >>
<div class='highlight-black'>
     text to highlight
</div>
 
css >>
.highlight-black {
background-color:black;
color:white;
}
```

---

**id way** / using `#`

```
html >>
<div id='highlight-black'>
     text to highlight
</div>
 
css >>
#highlight-black {
background-color:black;
color:white;
}
```

---

And one more thing that may come in handy in the future ...
if u use bootstrap, bootstrap automatically will highlight the text are between the mark tags.

have nice time

Answer (score 0):

Update your CSS

```
#highlight-black {
    background-color:black;
    color:white;
}
```

Better idea if you want highlight more than one text in the same document to set the class rather than ID attribute update your HTML with the following code

```
<div class='highlight-black'>
   text to highlight
</div>
```

Comment: It is a very bad idea to use an identifier to define the highlight. Use only the class.

Answer (score 0):

`.` is to target classes. `#` is to target id's.  Your div is using an ID.

So use this code:

```
#highlight-black {
    background-color:black;
    color:white;
}
```